# java program that finds average with average method

Tags: java, methods, syntax, program-entry-point

I have a program that will average your numbers from the command line. Everything is in the main method. 
1. The program should run allowing you to enter one number at a time and when you press enter it asks you for another number or offers the ability to press Q to get your average. 
2. The program has a limit set to 20 numbers added. When you hit 21 the program notifies you that you added to many numbers and shuts down.
3. If you enter multiple numbers on the same line and press enter, for every number you enter it System.out.println a message once for every number instead of just once.

I would like to understand how to change the program to do these things.

1. How to get the System.out.println to only appear one time per entry.
2. How to get the program to output the average of 20 before it ends when someone enters 21
3. how do i change it to create a method for averaging outside of main then call on the averaging method inside the main.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   class programTwo {

   public static void main (String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       double sum = 0;
       int count = 0;
       System.out.println ("Enter your numbers to be averaged:");
       String inputs = scan.nextLine();

       while (!inputs.contains("q")) {
           Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(inputs); // create a new scanner out of our single line of input

           while(scan2.hasNextDouble()) {
               sum += scan2.nextDouble();
               count += 1;
               System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");
           } 

           if(count == 21)
           {
               System.out.println("You entered too many numbers! Fail.");
               return;
           }
           inputs = scan.nextLine();
       }
       System.out.println("Your average is: " + (sum/count));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
scan2.hasNextDouble()
```

is parsing the line which contains multiple entries so it must be removed in the while loop. You can parse yourself using string tokenize and print the message only once.

2 . Simply add this line:

> System.out.println("Your average is: " + (sum/count));

before returning in if condition to print the average before quitting.

3 . that really depends on what kind of function would you like. May be you can create a function that takes an array of numbers and prints out their average or maybe you want something else.

one possible function:

```
public double findAverage(ArrayList<Integer> numbers){
    int sum=0;
    for (Integer i: numbers){
        sum+=i;
    }
    return sum/(double)numbers.size();
}
```

Comment: I was reading about putting the numbers in a string class. so is the only way to do this by storing the numbers that are scanned for the averaging method to grab them and average them when called? I keep trying to come up with stuff but cant seem to get it to work

Comment: You could use BufferedReader to read the inputs from user and then it will be stored in string. You can tokenize the string to get multiple numbers as string array. You can do a lot of things, just go out there and experiment.

Comment: ok so what if I take the numbers the scanner class finds and store them in a list array? then create a method that grabs those numbers from the list array and averages them. then call on that method in place of System.out.println("Your average is: " + (sum/count)); ??? Is this logical?

Comment: yes it is completely logical. You store them in an ArrayList, pass the list to a method which simply iterates and sums and divides by the size of ArrayList to return the average . This kind of method will also qualify for code re usability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  if(args.length==20)
  {
    int sum=0;
    sum += Integer.parseInt(args[0]); //do this for 20 array elements using loop 
    // do required calculation
  }
  else //print error message
}
```